# Oracle Clear Cached Sequence

Tags: oracle, caching, sequence

I have a very simple table that has an ID (generated by a sequence), and a NAME. I inserted a couple rows which got cached but after a while I wanted to remove them because I wanted to redo my table so I issued a couple of DELETE statements to remove all records (I don't have the privileges to do a TRUNCATE).

After deleting the old rows, I again inserted a couple other records but I didn't bother resetting the sequence.

On PHP, when I SELECT everything on that table, I still get those old deleted rows. But on PL/SQL when I SELECT on that table, it only shows me the new records.

Is the problematic cache on the PHP or Oracle side? If it's on the Oracle side, how do I clear it out?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you committed the delete and insert?

Comment: I only called commit after the new inserts. I didn't do a commit when I did a delete.

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed that problem. Thanks! I'm just so much more used to MySQL. Oracle is new to me.

Comment: Oracle does not auto-commit as SQL Server does by default. That difference bites me on occasion still.